# Django verbose logging for bad request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-logging

I am relatively new to django. I recently deployed my application on a web server, and I find it very hard to debug issues. I am getting a 400 Http status code for some of my requests and not sure why. I am trying to increase the level of logs in order to find the root cause for it. However, the output of the logs in not very informative.
I am using this configuration for logging (DEBUG is enabled):

```
logging.config.dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'console': {
            'format': '%(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s'
            },
        'file': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s'
            }
        },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'console'
            },
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'formatter': 'file',
            'filename': '/var/log/django/debug.log'
            }
        },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console', 'file']
            }
        }
    })
```

This is the output that I am getting in the logs:

```
2021-11-18 16:18:59,667 django.request WARNING  Bad Request: /create
```

How can I increase the verbosity of the logs to be more informative?

Answer (score 0):

`console` handler doesn't have a `level` set. Might want to set to `INFO` or `DEBUG`?